# Windows Error: 32 when trying to rename file in python

Tags: python, rename, pypdf

I'm trying to rename some PDF files using pyPdf and my code it seems to work fine until it reaches the rename sentence. The While/if 
block of code looks for the page number where string "This string" is located and when found stops. Having the page number the "new name"
is created.

My issue is that even when the with block it's supposed to close automatically the file, when it's reached the rename sentence I get the 
error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 14, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

and I don't know how to close the file before rename it, since if I use "file.close()" I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 14, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```

My current code is below, thanks for any help on this.

```
import os
import glob
import sys
from os.path import basename
import pyPdf

path = "C:\\My\\Path\\"
os.chdir(path)  
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
    print file
    i = 0
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(f)
        while True:
            txt = pdf.pages[i].extractText()
            if "This string" in txt:
                new_name = basename(file) + "_Page_" + str(i)
                break
            i = i + 1   
    print new_name
    #file.close()
    os.rename(file, new_name) # The error occurs here.
```

*** Update ***

Without With block I get the same error

```
for file in glob.glob("*pdf"):
    print file
    i = 0   
    f = open(file, "rb") 
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(f)
    while True:
        txt = pdf.pages[i].extractText()
        if "This string" in txt:
            new_name = basename(file) + "_Page_" + str(i)
            break           
        i = i + 1   
    f.close()   
    os.rename(file, new_name)
```

Comment: `file` is just the filename. `f` is your file handle, try `f.close()`

Comment: Hello Marc, thanks for help, but I get the same error using f.close() within the With or inmediately before os.rename.

Comment: try handle the file without the `with` statement like f=open(...), do your thing, and then f.close()

Comment: Hi Copperfield, thanks for your help. I tried as you mention and the same error. Please se my update in original post.

Comment: Are you sure your file is not open in another process, like a pdf viewer?

Comment: the code as you have it right now, works at my place.
Do keep in mind the file.close() is commented out.
The Windows Error 32 only occurs when you have the pdf file opened at the moment you try to rename it. Windows is infamous for not allowing this.

Comment: I close files and folder explorer and python process and run script again and now it seems to work. I'm not sure why suddenly appears that error ut now is gone. Many thanks to all for your suggestions. Merry Christmas!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks your advice .But,I remove the variable in my program,and successed.  :)
In  my view ,the file was surely opened in my program ,but I dont know how to c lose it,So I  clean All. :(